# DJANGO: ManyToManyField blank select option missing in form

Tags: python, django, forms, widget, many-to-many

I have the following Form constructed in my View

VIEW.PY

```
class MembershipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    project = forms.ModelChoiceField(Project, required=True)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True)
```

MODEL.PY

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True, null=True)
```

In my template, there is no "---------" option for role. How can I have this as an option and have it selected by default?

Comment: Also note, that you're using a models.FIELD in a form, which is incorrect. You can't use the models.ManyToManyField as a form field. It is exclusively a model field.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your MembershipForm looks incorrect. Fix it by either

```
class MembershipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Do you really need to override the form field for role?
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
```

or something else.

Secondly, for ManyToManyField, empty label '--------' is not used, because widget could represent the state that no items is picked, and its confusing to have both an empty label and an actual item picked.

Comment: how do I create a widget to represent a no items picked state?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the blank option is missing is the view, but to set a default value use a [default field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default).

```
class Membership
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True, null=True, default = "")
```